# Virtual Box, Vagrant, Docker - vmdk ssh damaged?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, docker, vagrant

CentOS 7 host o/s, guest o/s.

VirtualBox-6.0-6.0.4_128413_el7-1.x86_64

Virtualbox Guest Additions 6.0.4

Host kernel 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64

Guest kernel 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64

Guest file systems are ext4.  Verified that "d_type=true"

We've provisioned a Virtual Box VM, are able to "vagrant halt", "vagrant up" and "vagrant ssh", no problems.

Next, installed docker-ce in the guest.

vagrant halt, vagrant up, we get this:
The configured shell (config.ssh.shell) is invalid and unable
to properly execute commands.

We've been using this VM for a couple of years now, looking to determined what has changed.

The docker version is a bit older, docker-ce-17.09.1.ce-1.el7.centos

Next step, upgrade docker in the VM, docker-ce-18.09.5-3.el7.x86_64

**Same problem:**

The configured shell (config.ssh.shell) is invalid and unable
to properly execute commands.

Comment: Additional observation: vagrant ssh
Last login: Mon Apr 15 17:38:09 2019 from 10.0.2.2
Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine.
/bin/bash: Permission denied
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

Comment: What is the current value of `config.ssh.shell` that Vagrant is trying to use?  You should have `config.ssh.shell` set somewhere in your Vagrantfile.  According to your comment, it is possibly set to `/bin/bash` so seeing the permissions on that file (inside the VM) may help too.

Comment: I don't have config.ssh.shell set.  Before installing Docker in the VM, vagrant ssh is OK, no error.  After the problem presented, I did try setting config.ssh.shell to 'sh', but, in redhat derived centos, IIRC, /bin/sh is a link to /bin/bash.  (and found that in the VMDK virtual disk file, mounting to a running VM, /bin/bash permissions are OK.  Whatever the problem is, it is quite perplexing!)

Comment: OK, I've won the dummy award!  selinux was on, but restorecon was not run at all.

Comment: Thank you to GracefulRestart for sending me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

selinux was on, but restorecon was not run at all.
Somehow in our provisioning this happened, possibly yum install'ing docker-ce.